# FSTR for Alfresco 3.4

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I want to use the File System Transfer Receiver with my Alfresco 3.4 Community Edition.

I've only been able to find FSTR for Alfresco 4 and up.

Is there any version of the FSTR available for this Alfresco version ?

Where can I find it ?

Answer (score 1):

Prior to version 4 this was part of the WCM product. You can find the AVM files for 3.4 at:
http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Community_file_list_3.4.d

What you are looking for is the Deployment and Deployment Receiver files.

Answer (score -1):

At http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Community_file_list_4.2.f you can find the latest community release packages. Pick one the "alfresco-community-deployment" named files under "Alfresco WCM".